# Android Picture Gallery JSON / SQLite w/ variable number of Images

Tags: android, json, image, sqlite

**MY GOAL**

So I want to parse pictures for a Picture Gallery in my Android App. Let's say I have *5 (or more) Picture Galleries, each with a variable number of Images in it*

My GalleryOverview gives me my ListView with let's say

- Thumbnail
- Description
- Date

clicking on one Item in the ListView give me the whole gallery in PictureDetail Activity. Clicking on the Pic itself, it opens SinglePicture Activity to give me the Pic in full resolution

**CURRENT STATUS**

So, the Activity Tree wasn't the problem, I'm able to parse and load 1 Gallery with a static amount of pics in it.
Where I fail: JSON-Parsing (which structure is choosen by myself) and inserting in a local SQLTable

**OVERVIEW.CLASS**

```
public class Overview extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_recyclerview_allimages);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_images);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    Overview.ImageGalleryAdapter adapter = new Overview.ImageGalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(),SinglePicture.getSpacePhotos());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class ImageGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    @Override
    public ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the layout
        View photoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_costume_item_layout, parent, false);

        ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = new ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder(photoView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SinglePicture spacePhoto = mSpacePhotos[position];
        ImageView imageView = holder.mPhotoImageView;

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(spacePhoto.getUrl())
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mSpacePhotos.length);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView mPhotoImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                SinglePicture spacePhoto = mSpacePhotos[position];

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PictureDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra(PictureDetail.EXTRA_SPACE_PHOTO, spacePhoto);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private SinglePicture[] mSpacePhotos;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context, SinglePicture[] spacePhotos) {
        mContext = context;
        mSpacePhotos = spacePhotos;
    }
}
```

}

**PICTURE DETAIL**

```
public class PictureDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_SPACE_PHOTO = "PictureDetail.SPACE_PHOTO";

private ImageView mImageView;

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_detail);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    SinglePicture spacePhoto = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_SPACE_PHOTO);

    Glide.with(this)

            .asBitmap()

            .load(spacePhoto.getUrl())

            //.listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>()
            .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }



                public void onPalette(Palette palette) {
                    if (null != palette) {
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mImageView.getParent().getParent();
                        parent.setBackgroundColor(palette.getDarkVibrantColor(Color.GRAY));
                    }
                }
            })

            .into(mImageView);

}
```

}

**PARSING the JSON**

```
public class JSON_GallReader extends AppCompatActivity {


SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
String HttpJSonURL = config.JSON_GL;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.json_reader);

    SQLiteDataBaseBuild();
    SQLiteTableBuild();
    DeletePreviousData();

    new StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass(JSON_GallReader.this).execute();

}

private class StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public Context context;

    String FinalJSonResult;


    public StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(JSON_GallReader.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("LOADING");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = new HttpServiceClass(HttpJSonURL);

        try {
            httpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest();


            if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();

                if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(FinalJSonResult);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray gallery = jsonObj.getJSONArray("gallery");


                        // looping through the Gallery
                        for (int i = 0; i < gallery.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = gallery.getJSONObject(i);
                            final int id = i;
                            String jr_id = c.getString("id");
                            String jr_descr = c.getString("cover");
                            String jr_name = c.getString("title");
                            String jr_date = c.getString("descr");
```

** HERE IS THE PROBLEM**

```
                            String SQLiteDataBaseQuery = "INSERT INTO overall_table (id,des,name,date,imgurl,fburl,fbid) VALUES('"+id+"', '"+jr_descr+"',** HERE IS THE PROBLEM** );";

                            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQuery);



                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {
        sqLiteDatabase.close();

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(JSON_Reader.this,"Load Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


public void SQLiteDataBaseBuild(){

    sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

}


public void SQLiteTableBuild(){

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+SQLiteHelper.TAB_NAME+"("+SQLiteHelper.table_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + SQLiteHelper.table_desc+" VARCHAR, " and so on..


}


public void DeletePreviousData(){

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TAB_NAME+"");

}
```

}

Current JSON (feel free to edit also this one)

```
{
  "gallery": [
    {
      "cover": "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
      "title": "Test Gallery 1",
      "desc": "Here you go number one",
      "pics": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cover": "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
      "title": "Here you go number 2",
      "desc": "Hier steht die Beschreibung zur Gallery",
      "pics": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cover": "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
      "title": "Here you go number three",
      "desc": "Hier steht die Beschreibung zur Gallery",
      "pics": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/creator-academy-assets/thumbnails/thumbnails-z1-1.png"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**THE PROBLEMS**

As you can see, in my JSON_GallReader when I loop through my JSON lenght, I don't really get how to loop trough one array (gallery) which makes part of the "pics" array - basically I'm able with
JSONArray pics= jsonObj.getJSONArray("pics");
and
for (int j = 0; j < pics.length(); j++) {
...

BUT

Is there any way to put all my Links in 1 Table, or do I have to create a saperate table for all the links?

My second thought was the following: Maybe I should get two JSONs, one's for parsing the image galleries and one contains only the IMG Links which will be parsed on the fly when clicking on the ListView Item. Would that be better? 
I'm using GLIDE btw.

Answer (score 0):

you can store all pics array into a single list by following code

```
List<String> pics_list =new ArrayList();
JsonObject response=new JsonObject(s);
JsonArray gallery =response.getJsonArray("gallery");
if(gallery!=null && gallery.length()>0){
for(int i=0;i<gallery.length();i++){
JsonObject json=gallery.getJsonObject(i);
JsonArray pics =json.getJsonArray("pics");
String [] arr=new String[pics.length];
for(int j=0; j<pics.length();j++){

arr[j]=pics.optstring(i);

}
for(int k=0 ;k<arr.length();k++){
pics_list.add(arr[k]);
}


}
```

}

after that you can save this list into database by using update or create command in sqlite

Comment: Thanks a lot! What's your opinion, should I insert the image-links now in the same sql-database as the cover,title,descr parts or create a separate database? I'm thinking of a Query like this: "INSERT INTO images_table (id,cover,title,desc,IMGURLSHERE) VALUES('"+i+"', '"+jr_cover+"', '"+jr_title+"', '"+jr_desc+"', '"+arr+"');"; only with arr[1] arr[2] and so on ... what would you suggest me?

Comment: You can store all images in single table and can use insert statement for faster instertion

Comment: Thanks, Mohit. It is helpfull for me

Comment: ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
                                    for (int u=0; u < pics_list.size(); u++)
                                    {
                                        values.get(pics_list.get(u)) ;

                                    } sqLiteDatabase.insert("images_table",imgurl,values);  +++ Here my "imgurl" is static, I need a dynamic amount of imgurl columns.. How can I realize that?

Comment: My problem is, that the amount of img-links coloumns should be dynamic, so maybe gallery[0] has 10 urls in the pics array, gallery[1] has 11 urls.. I think there will be a big problem, if afterwards I'm looping through row[0] and there is coloumn [11] not defined at the beginning